# how to do intercept scan in hbase coprocessor

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase, secondary-indexes

how can you intercept what is being queried in hbase? I saw that you can intercept `preGetOp` and `preScannerOpen` but I can't figure out to see what `column families` and `column qualifiers` are being queried. how do you see that?

I am willing to write a coprocessor to intercept the query and search in a secondary-indexed table...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `Scan` object that you get as a parameter to the preScannerOpen method - it has methods like `getFamilies`, `getFilter` etc.

Comment: have you tried this? and I get only `families`... I also need `qualifiers`